# Div is not responding to css

Tags: html, css

I have created 3 div's that are not responding to the css code. 
I wanted to make the width of the div at max 30% but its displayed much bigger.
 The text box containing the Name of the images is scaling according to the size but the images and the div's are not.

This is the html code:

```
<div id='item' align = center style='padding:40px; background-color:white;'>
<div id='item_box'> 
<a href='travel.php?id=".$row['cityid']."&name=".$row['cityname']."'>
<img class='cityimg' src='images/city/".($row['cityname']).".jpg'/></a>    </div>
<div id='item_cityname' align=center style='padding:15px; background-color:#004b79;' > ".$row['cityname']." </div>
</div>"
```

And this is the css code:

```
#item{

max-width: 30%;

}

#item_box{
max-width: 30%;  
}


#item_cityname{ 
max-width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: try width instead of max-width

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
#item{

max-width: 30%;

}

#item_box{
max-width: 30%;  
}


#item_cityname{ 
max-width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at your ID or CLASS definition in HTML or CSS, they are not matching!

```css
#item{

max-width: 30%;

}

#item_box{
max-width: 30%;  
}


#item_cityname{ 
max-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id='item' align = center style='padding:40px; background-color:white;'>
  <div id='item_box'> 
    <a href='travel.php?id=".$row['cityid']."&name=".$row['cityname']."'>
      <img class='cityimg' src='images/city/".($row['cityname']).".jpg'/>
    </a>    
  </div>
  <div id='item_cityname' align=center style='padding:15px; background-color:#004b79;' > ".$row['cityname']." 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS targets classes but your code uses ids. If you want to target the ids then use `#` instead of `.` in the CSS. Else change `id` to `class` in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your using ID's in your html, but trying to target classes (.) in our css. So that is why your css is not responding.

For the images not scaling, do the images have a width that is greater than the width of the div?

One thing you could try is adding max-width:100%; and height: auto; in css to the img tag or you can target the specific images using the ID or class.

So something like this:

`img {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}`

or for the image in your code snippet

`.cityimg {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
}`

This way your image will never be wider than the container div. The height: auto will help ensure the image keeps it's proportions when scaling.

And just as a side note, your ID's item, item_box and item_cityname seem a little to generic, like they would get used for all 3 of your divs, which would cause a validation error for having duplicate ID's. I would suggest adding classes that you can apply to all 3 divs and use those classes to style.